# ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER privilege

Tags: oracle, trigger, permissions

What does **ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER** privilege actually mean?

I have the following case:

I have 2 databases: **DB1** and **DB2**

On **DB1** I have a trigger which arises after logon on database and checks if this username exists in some table. If not raises application error like "You are not permitted to log on!"

I created link on **DB2**, which is connecting to **DB1** by some username, for example by **kupa_dba**.

Note that **kupa_dba** is not in an access list(in the table storing usernames that can connect to the database)

If **kupa_dba** doesn't have **ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER** than trigger works, BUT if **kupa_dba** has **ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER**  privilege there is no application error raising, trigger is ignored and **DB2** can retrieve data from **DB1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` privilege allows you to create database-level triggers (server error, login, and logout triggers).  It also allows you to log in regardless of errors thrown by a login trigger as a failsafe.  If you inadvertently coded your login trigger to throw an error no matter who was logging in, for example, you need to allow someone to log in to fix the trigger.

It appears that the trigger is behaving as expected in this case.  You wouldn't in reality create a database link from one database to another using a DBA account.